# Testing vuetify v-select with laravel dusk

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-dusk, browser-testing, vuetify.js

Does anyone know how to test vuetify v-select with laravel dusk?

I've tried `$browser->select('size', 'Large');` without success

this is one of the v-selects that i want to test

```
 <v-flex class="form__item">
       <v-select
                    id="estatus"
                    dusk="estatus"
                    v-model="form.id_estatus"
                    label="Estatus"
                    :items="estatus"
                    item-text="nombre"
                    item-value="id"
                    v-validate="{ required:true }"
                    data-vv-name="estatus"
                    data-vv-as="estatus"
                    :error-messages="(errors.collect('estatus'))"
                    required
        ></v-select>
  </v-flex>
```

And this the generated HTML

[image]

When v-select is clicked, shows the option list in other part of the HTML

[image]

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML?

Comment: i've updated my question

Comment: Can you please create a minimal example on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: here is a minimal v-select exampple https://jsfiddle.net/v41pyq53/9/

Answer (score 4):

Click on the `.v-select` element and wait for the select to open up:

```php
$browser->click('.v-select');
$browser->waitFor('.v-menu__content');
```

Then you can select an option by index:

```php
$browser->elements('.v-menu__content a')[2]->click();
```

Or by text (using XPath):

```php
$selector = "//div[@class='v-menu__content menuable__content__active']//div[text()='State 3']";
$browser->driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath($selector))->click();
```

Comment: how you suppose to handle more than one v-select?

Answer (score 1):

**(1)** In the Vue template:

Wrap the `<v-select>` with a `<div id="selectStatus"></div>`

**(2)** In the Dusk test, use:

```
  $browser->click('#selectStatus .v-select');
  $browser->waitFor('.menuable__content__active');
  $browser->elements('.menuable__content__active a')[1]->click();
  $browser->waitUntilMissing('.menuable__content__active');
  $browser->assertSeeIn('#selectStatus .v-select','theStatusIExpectToSee');
```

**— OR —**

The `<v-select>` can be tested *without* wrapping it in a `<div id="foo"></div>` if we use a slightly more complicated strategy.

Instead of putting the `id` on a `div` wrapper, we can put the `id` directly on the `v-select` or even rely on text content contained within the `v-select` with the following strategy (involving `xpath`):

```
use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverBy;

  public function keyOfParentContainingItem($elements, $itemName, $itemValue = null){
    $elWithItemKey = null;
    $itemNamePrefix = ($itemName !== 'text()') ? '@' : '';
    $itemValueMatchString = ($itemValue !== null) ? '="'.$itemValue.'"' : '';
    foreach($elements as $k=>$v){
      $xpath = './/*['.$itemNamePrefix.$itemName.$itemValueMatchString.']';
      if(!empty($v->findElements(WebDriverBy::xpath($xpath)))){
        $elWithItemKey = $k;
      }
    }
    return $elWithItemKey;
  }

  public function testMyVSelect(){
    $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
      $browser->visit('/myAddress');
      $els = $browser->elements('.v-select');
      $els[$this->keyOfParentContainingItem($els,'id','idOnVSelect')]->click();
      $browser->waitFor('.menuable__content__active');
      $menuEls = $browser->elements('.menuable__content__active a');
      $menuEls[$this->keyOfParentContainingItem($menuEls,'text()',"some text")]->click();
      $browser->waitUntilMissing('.menuable__content__active');
      $els = $browser->elements('.v-select');
      $key = $this->keyOfParentContainingItem($els,'text()',"some text");
      $this->assertTrue($key !== null);
    });
  }
```

Using `Vuetify 1.5.14`.

Comment: Note: we can take advantage of the fact that `Browser` has the `Macroable` trait to further simplify the above code, as described [here](https://medium.com/@splatEric/writing-tests-with-laravel-dusk-bb755c0dcb1f).

Answer (score 0):

Click on the v-select element for it to list the options, then wait for the dropdown-menu class to be present before selecting an element from the list (2 in the example below) by clicking on the third  tag in the menu list.
Finally, wait until the dropdown-menu class disappears before moving onto the next part of the test.

```
$browser->click('#region')
    ->with('#region', function ($vSelect) {
        $vSelect->waitFor('.dropdown-menu')
            ->elements('.dropdown-menu a')[2]->click();
    })
    ->waitUntilMissing('.dropdown-menu');
```